# How to save a message with a command and then get the message with another command using json?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I really don't know how to describe it in the title, so I'll clarify more here.

Me and my friend own a Discord server where we share homework answers with other classmates. We do so using a bot, and every time they call a command for a specific subject (e.g !ela or !math), it gives the answer for that subject.

The problem is, this has been getting difficult to do, since me and my friend have been getting busier and busier and don't have the time to keep going into the code and changing it.

So basically, I need to create a command (sorta like !hwadd (subject) (link to homework answers download) which will save the subject and answers to a .json file, and then when someone calls the command for the subject (e.g !math), it will return with the link for that subject.

Problem is, I don't know much about using a .json file. Can anyone help?

Comment: As long as you understand how dictionaries work, you can dump a dictionary into a json file using `import json` `file = open('homework.json', 'w')` `json.dump(dict(), file)`

Comment: @Judev1 I did it, and it works, however how do I go about getting back that data?

Comment: You can retrieve the data using `with open('homework.json', 'r') as homeworkfile`  and then using `json.loads(homeworkfile.read())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hahahhaa, I have a very similar bot instead my classmates are constantly pinging everyone for what is due so I also made a hw bot.

Here's a simple example (cog btw);

```
@commands.command
async def math(self, ctx):
  with open("math.json","r") as f:
     math = json.load(f)
  await ctx.send(f"{math}")
```

Now making the `addhw` command

```
@commands.command
async def addmath(self, ctx, *, hw):
  with open("math.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(hw,f)
  await ctx.send("Added Math!")
```

And that's it! Very simple.

Comment: Thanks! This method worked perfectly for me!